# using expressions in ContentValues for update

Tags: android, datetime, sqlite, sql-update

I'm trying to do something in Android 10 like;

```
UPDATE MY_TABLE SET DATE_FIELD = date(DATE_FIELD, '+1 days') WHERE _ID=123
```

Now I can see that sqlite3 supports various [date functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) but it seems that
the [ContentResolver.update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String where, String[] selectionArgs)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#update%28android.net.Uri,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) method doesn't support this approach, since if I use;

```
ContentValues values= new ContentValues();
values.put("DATE_FIELD", "date(DATE_FIELD, '+1 days')");
getContentResolver().update(updateUri, values, null, null);
```

It simply places the string `"date(DATE_FIELD, '+1 days')"` as the value for `DATE_FIELD`.

Is there a way to perform this sort of computed expression update using this method, or should I use a different approach?

Comment: Did you find any answers for this? Have the same question.